# Behavioural differences between JSF 1.X and JSF 2.X tags

Tags: jsf-2, jsf-1.2

Recently we have upgraded our solution from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.2.

However it is observed, there are some behaviour changes in terms of rendering and actions on certain JSF tags especially datatable.

So wanted to know if there are any such changes introduced if so request you to share some information. I tried to find info on Oracle and other discussion site but did not get any concrete information.

Request you to share details.

Best Regards
Sudhakar

Comment: Seriously, 2.0?  Why not 2.2. And stackoverflow usually worms the other way around. You post explicit coding problems each in its own question  and we try to help you with each of them

Comment: I mean it is 2.2 only.

Comment: @Kukeltje SO worms in mysterious ways.

Comment: Please post specific issues. Create a [mcve] and post what the difference is and why it effectively is a problem. @DaveNewton: hahaha sorry... typo: works